# How can we use solr with both MongoDB and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, solr

I want to use `Solr` with `MongoDB` and `MySQL` together and need to combine in single core.

For example, I have a MongoDB collection which has depends on MySQL's one table,

I tried both with separate Solr core it's working fine but i want it in single core, i don't know its possible or not, if its possible then how we can use?

### Updated

Here my DIHs: *(Data import Handler)*

**- Solr with MySQL**

```xml
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource 
        name="MySQl" 
        type="JdbcDataSource"
        driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
        user="root" password="root" 
        batchSize="-1"/>
    <document> 
        <entity 
            query="select * from master_table"
            name="master">                      
        </entity>   
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

**- Solr with MongoDB**

```xml
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource 
        name="MyMongo" 
        type="MongoDataSource" 
        database="test" />
    <document>   
        <entity  
             processor="MongoEntityProcessor"
             query=""
             collection="MarketCity"   
             datasource="MyMongo"
             transformer="MongoMapperTransformer" 
             name="sample_entity">
                 <field column="_id"  name="id" mongoField="_id" />            
                 <field column="keyName" name="keyName" mongoField="keyName"/>                            
        </entity>   
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

So i want to do with the single core.

Comment: Do you need to know how to index table from MySQL to Solr?

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question that’s difficult to answer concisely and is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. Instead of leaving us to speculate on what you might need, give us something to build so we can focus help in those areas where it’s most needed.

Comment: Write an indexing script that pulls the data you need from MongoDB and MySQL and merges it appropriately before pushing it to Solr?

Comment: @SaidbakR Thank you for your reply ,i know that process and i'm using it. I want to use solr with mongo and mysql together to get the data from both of them simultaneously.

Comment: @MansiJoshi please edit your question and describe the scenario in details. However, if I well understand, it is not possible.

Comment: @tadman and SaidbakR updated my answer with my DIH.

Comment: @MatsLindh can you explain how and where i use indexing script ,i don't know about it.Thank you.

Comment: @MansiJoshi You'd write a small program in a language you're familiar with that connects to mongodb, retrieves the documents you want to index, then connect to MySQL and retrieve the extra metadata for those documents and then push them to Solr. You can do this in Java, python, javascript, PHP - any language with a HTTP client (and most have dedicated Solr clients as well). It'll give you exactly the result you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the data from Mysql and MongoDB. Merge this records in single record and the index the same into solr.

To get the data from MySql, use any programming language and fetch the data.
For example you can use Java and fetch the data from mysql.
Apply the same logic to MongoDB. Get all the required records from mongoDB using Java.

Now By using the SolrJ apis create the solrDocument. Read more about the SolrDOcument and other apis [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_5_2/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/SolrDocument.html)

Once your create the instance of SolrDocument then add the data that you fetched from Mysql and MongoDB into it using the below method.

```
addField(String name, Object value)
```

This will add a field to the document.

You can prepare the document something like this.

```
SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
document.addField("id", "123456");
document.addField("name", "Kevin Ross");
document.addField("price", "100.00");
solr.add(document);
solr.commit();
```

Get a solr instance of `HttpSolrClient`.
Once the SolrDocument is ready, index it to solr.

Comment: Do you have any idea about this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/62596805/9450155.